# Mobile Change Page Error - Jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a page which creates a listview after getting the list from an external php file. When I click on a button on the page (which brings up a dialog box), and then close the dialog box, the list dissapears how can i fix that...

HTML
//Page with the listview

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" align="right" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#create" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">
            Create
        </a>
        <a href="#join" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">
            Join
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="ccontent" data-inset="true">

    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

HTML //Page with the input (dialog box)

```
<div data-role="page" id="create">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Create</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <form id="name" align="left">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true">
    </form>


    <div id="result" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT //after the input is submitted

```
$("#name").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: 'some url',
crossDomain: true,
type: 'post',
data: $("#name").serialize(),
success: function (data) {
$("#result").html(data);
$('#ccontent').listview('refresh');
},
});
});
```

JAVASCRIPT //gets information from external source to make a list

```
function getClubs() {
$.ajax({
url: 'some url',
crossDomain: true,
type: 'post',
data: '',
success: function (data) {
$('#ccontent').empty();
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
$('#ccontent').append('<li><a href="#" data-club-id=\"' + json[i].id + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>');
$('#ccontent').listview('refresh');
},
});
}
```

JAVASCRIPT //calls getclubs

```
$('#page-tasklist').ready(function() {
    getClubs();
});
```

Comment: Are the pages inside a single HTML file (multipage approach) or in different HTML files (multiple pages approach)?

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis single HTML file

Comment: Why do you refresh the ccontent list (`$('#ccontent').listview('refresh');`) on the form submission success function?

Comment: because after the person submits, that thing that they submitted should be added to the list EDIT: is there a way, that after submit, the whole page is refreshed?

Comment: But you append the data on the result div `$("#result").html(data);` not on the ccontent ul. Could you post your single HTML file? It would help a lot to locate the issue.

Comment: Is there any way i can email it to you, its very long...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31493/discussion-between-nshah-and-tolis-emmanouilidis)

Comment: why are you using? `.ready()`? you close the dialog and it takes you to which page, the same page?